# DNSJava 2.1.8 as dependency invalidates JPMS (Java 9 Platform Module System) compatibility

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system, dnsjava

There is a maven artifact called `xxx`:

Having this vanilla pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dnsjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>dnsjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And this java-class (Test):

```
package xxx;

import org.xbill.DNS.Lookup;

public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Lookup.class.getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

Now, the artifact should be a module (Java 9 Platform Module System). So I ask eclipse to create that `module-info.java`

[image]

This works fine so far. The `module-info.java` have this contents:

```
module xxx {
    exports xxx;
    requires dnsjava;
}
```

Then I try to build the jar using `mvn install`. But the Build faild. This is the output:

```
grim@main:~/workspace/xxx$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------< aaa:xxx >-------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxx 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ xxx ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/grim/workspace/xxx/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ xxx ---
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from dnsjava-2.1.8.jar: lookup.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/grim/workspace/xxx/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/grim/workspace/xxx/src/main/java/module-info.java:[4,18] module not found: dnsjava
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.278 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-13T22:36:07+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project xxx: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/grim/workspace/xxx/src/main/java/module-info.java:[4,18] module not found: dnsjava
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
grim@main:~/workspace/xxx$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your title is back to front.

Comment: @user207421 I do not think so. I tried many other dependencies that works great to build the JPMS module, only DNSJava break the build of the JPMS module. So DNSJava is the stranger here, not JPMS.

Comment: Your title says that JPMS is invalidated. That’s wrong by definition. A specification can’t be invalid. What you mean is that JPMS invalidates DNSJava.

Comment: @user207421 That is totally correct. Would you mind be so kind to suggest a better title? Would you agree if I say `... invalidates JPMS compabtibility`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `dnsjava-2.1.8.jar` contains classes in the root of the JAR. This is not allowed for a modular JAR, so Java will not consider it a module. A module cannot have any classes in the unnamed package (other than `module-info.class`). As a result no module called `dnsjava` is present, leading to the error *"module not found: dnsjava"*.

This is also reported in your Maven output:

> [WARNING] Can't extract module name from dnsjava-2.1.8.jar: lookup.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

However, the solution to your problem might be easy: upgrade to a newer version of dnsjava. For example, version 3.5.2 — the latest version at this time — declares an `Automatic-Module-Name` in its manifest, `org.dnsjava` (this seems to have been introduced in version 3.0.0), and does not contain any classes in its root.

In short:

1. Upgrade to version 3.5.2
2. Use `requires org.dnsjava;` instead of `requires dnsjava;` in `module-info.java`

Comment: I think I already used the latest version of DNSJava. Ill try 3.5.2

Comment: @Grim Your question shows you're using 2.1.8. And the important detail when using 3.5.2 is to use the right module name: `org.dnsjava`.

Comment: Resource files in the root are not a problem, only classes are.

Comment: Well, this was my first bet too, to take latest version of DNSJava. I tried both, 2.1.8 - wrote the question - and then took 3.5.2. But still faild and I did not update the question - See, I executed the eclipse-function for generate the `module-info.java` with version 2.1.8. Maybe I need repeat that for 3.5.2. Give me a moment please.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I removed the `module-info.java` then updated to latest version of DNSJava and then recreated the `module-info.java`. Now the build works perfectly fine!! Thanks!

Comment: One last comment. I am using the package-name of xxx. That is a bad name for a package. DNSJava had this bad name also. I will use the common pattern for package-names in the future just like DNSJava do.

Comment: @Grim Yes, the general recommendation is to use the reverse DNS of your company or project domain as the root name of your packages (and module names). Though I would generally not recommend using _only_ the reverse domain name as a module name (nor the package name).

Comment: Yes, I remember an official recommendation. Also I have never seen the `www` subdomain in a package. Its very complex since my domain is `e-nexus.de` but my package is `de.e_nexus`.

Comment: @Grim Fundamentally, www is not part of your domain (it is a hostname that is in your domain). If your domain is `e-nexus.de`, the recommendation is to use module name `de.e_nexus.<project-specific-name>` The same goes for packages. The assumption is generally that you do not have a single project, nor a single module, so use the reverse domain as a namespace, and use more specific names per project.

Comment: Yes, hope a company does not name final.com or default.com or import.com because they are keywords and not allowed in the package name afaik.